# Memory allocation in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I have a Ubuntu operating system with 32 GB RAM. I am running a code that I expect it needs much memory (but less than 32GB). while running the code, I monitor the memory with "free -m" command. I see that my code just uses around 4GB memory, and after that it crashes and returns memory error. 
My Question is why it does not use more memory when I have free space, does the OS put a limit on the memory usage of each process?

What's s the solution? is there any configuration option to increase memory usage?

Comment: Memory can be fragmented, and if you are requesting too large a block, that cannot be met, this may explain your problem.

Comment: It's possible to have per-process resource limits. See the `ulimit` command.

Comment: 4GB, is your program compiled as a 32 bit executable? :)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how it crashes when it has allocated 4 GB, it sounds very much as if you're running in 32-bit mode. Have either installed a 32-bit variant of Ubuntu (check with `uname -m`), or otherwise still compiled this program as a 32-bit executable (check your compiled program with the `file` command)?

Comment: I am running on 64-bit mode, I wrote a python code to see what actually happens, I wrote 'while' loop which is always True, and in each iteration I appended an integer number to a list, I monitored the memory, it just used 2 GB RAM, and 400,000,000 iterations, and returned "MemoryError"

Comment: Is the program in the question a Python program?

Comment: @MOH: Also, just to be sure, how did you verify that you're running in 64-bit mode?

Comment: in the question it was a C code, but for testing I used a simple python code, uname -m returns i686

Comment: @MOH: If `uname -m` returns `i686`, then you are indeed not running in 64-bit mode. If you were, it would say `x86_64`.

Comment: So, is this caused by running in 32-bit?

Comment: @MOH: Yes. 32-bit mode implies 32-bit pointers, which implies a 4 GB address space (some of which is used by the kernel, so even less in practice). You can't use more memory than you have address space for.